# ASP.NET MVC4 + dropdownlist + onChange js event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, onchange

So I've got a dropdownlist in my View History:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlAccounts", null,  new { @onchange="onChange(this.value);" })
```

and I have this js event to replace the url ../History/ to ../History/2, ../History/5

```
function onChange(value) {
    window.location.href = value;
}
```

Instead it always adds the value to the current url. So I get History/2/5 for example after changing index in dropdown.

Comment: It is not required to add with '@' onchange attribute in htmlAttributes dictionary, prefix only attributes that are keywords in c# for example @class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting selected value correctly:

```
@onchange="onChange(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
```

And here is structure of the current page url:

```
hash: "#13612872"
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612838/asp-net-mvc4-dropdownlist-onchange-js-event/13612872#13612872"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/13612838/asp-net-mvc4-dropdownlist-onchange-js-event/13612872"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
```